# mysql query : How to join multiple table with statment

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have mysql query below. but it does not work.

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN isLevel = '1' THEN 'Mahasiswa'
        WHEN isLevel = '2' THEN 'Dosen'
        WHEN isLevel = '3' THEN 'Karyawan'
        ELSE 'Admin'
        END as level 
FROM mhs LEFT JOIN if(isLevel=1,'mahasiswa','dosen') ON username=iduser 
WHERE blabala.
```

if "isLevel=1" I want to join mhs with the mahasiswa table, if "isLevel=2" join mhs with the dosen table, ... How should I write the query?

please help me.
thanks.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to do a **conditional** join in this way: why not simply join to both?

Answer (score 1):

You can't join conditionally. But use 2 left joins to get both tables

```
Select  CASE
    WHEN isLevel = '1' THEN 'Mahasiswa'
    WHEN isLevel = '2' THEN 'Dosen'
    WHEN isLevel = '3' THEN 'Karyawan'
ELSE 'Admin'
END as level 
from mhs 
left join mahasiswa m on m.username=iduser
left join dosen d on d.username=iduser
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union statement here:

```
SELECT 'Mahasiswa' AS level
FROM mhs, mahasiswa

WHERE isLevel = 1
AND username = iduser

UNION ALL

SELECT CASE WHEN isLevel = 2 THEN 'Dosen' 
            WHEN isLevel = 3 THEN 'Karyawan' ELSE 'Admin' END AS level
FROM mhs, dosen

WHERE isLevel != 1
AND username = iduser;
```

Although this does seem a difficult way to do it.  You're probably better off in the long term putting the translations of the isLevel column into another table, so you can reuse.  Unless you really enjoy writing CASE statements a lot.